# Angular 2: If value exists show html

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives, angular2-services

At the moment i have a service that pulls values from a number of APIs that I have written. In the template i wish to only output the following html if the value exists or is not empty in the results when they are fed to the template:

```
<li class="title rh-blue-lite-fg">{{ project.meta_header_one }}</li>
```

so I am trying to figure out how to wrap this in ngIf or is there some other way to do this so that this 'li' item only gets output if that value is present and not empty

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you can use ngIF directive to check if project isn't null:

```
<li class="title rh-blue-lite-fg" *ngIf="project.meta_header_one">{{ project.meta_header_one }}</li>
```

Reference:
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgIf-directive.html

Comment: what if i have a number to check. Above code will work if you are checking for string.

Comment: transform the number to string it should be okay

Answer (score 1):

## Angular 4+

Using Angular 4 or later (*at least up to Angular 6*) you can use `*ngIf` with the `as` keyword to store the condition value in a variable like this:

```
<div *ngIf="condition as value">{{value}}</div>
```

This way you don't have to repeat the condition, which can be useful if the expression is long or contains method calls that you want to avoid calling more than once.

Applied to the code snippet from the question:

```
<li class="title rh-blue-lite-fg" *ngIf="project.meta_header_one as value">{{value}}</li>
```

*Reference: [*NgIf API Documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf#syntax)*